# SQL select from 3 tables with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, datatables, ssms

I have a simple query to figure out what assets a user updated after a certain time frame on a column.

```
SELECT asset_id,template_id,mod_date,mod_user_id
FROM [asset_attr]
WHERE mod_user_id = 11 AND template_id = '28' /*Artwork Image View*/   
  AND mod_date > '2022-08-25'
ORDER BY asset_id DESC
```

Though, when I go to expand this query to go to other tables to get actual readable values, I cant ever get the same amount of results. It is pulling in some garbage results.

For instance, if I expand on the above query and a table, `asset_attr_value`, it gets funky.

```
SELECT 
    asset_attr.asset_id, asset_attr.template_id, asset_attr.mod_date,  
    asset_attr.mod_user_id, asset_attr_value.option_set_item_id
FROM 
    asset_attr, asset_attr_value
WHERE 
    (asset_attr.asset_id = asset_attr_value.asset_id 
     AND asset_attr.template_id = asset_attr_value.template_id)
    AND asset_attr.mod_user_id = 11 
    AND asset_attr.template_id = '28' /*Artwork Image View*/ 
    AND asset_attr.mod_date > '2022-08-25'
ORDER BY 
    asset_attr.asset_id DESC
```

Comment: The title mentions "3 tables". I only see 2 in your queries, overall: `asset_attr` and `asset_attr_value`.

Comment: If you are getting "garbage results", then the chances are you are missing a join relating to foreign keys. But this is a guess because the question is missing necessary info for a definitive answer. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/12567365) for ways to improve the question, to make it more likely to receive helpful answers. You can also take a look at [ask] and its linked content for more background guidance.

Comment: Just as an aside, I'd recommend using [ANSI-92 join syntax](https://datacadamia.com/data/type/relation/sql/join_default_ansi92_comparison) as a way to make the joins between tables clearer (separate from other `WHERE` clauses). Personal preference.